# Problems with installing rJava package

Tags: java, r, xlsx

I have tried to call the library xlsx, since I want to save data in multiple-sheets excel files, but I got a Java-related error. Even when I run library(rJava) I have this error code:

Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘rJava’:
.onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
call: inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...)
error: unable to load shared object 'C:/Users/me/Documents/R/win-library/4.0/rJava/libs/x64/rJava.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.

The solutions I have found online are quite old and none helped to solve the issue: I have tried to reinstall Java 64 bit on my OS (Windows 10-64bit), and the package rJava, I have tried to set Java home with Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_271\") without success. I use R 64 bit.
Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, the solution reported [here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/exporting-to-excel-results-from-dear/57279/5) worked for me. The most important thing is to download the offline version of Java